# Uppercase only the first letter of each line

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I am trying `sed s/\w/\u/g` but it doesn't do anything. I think because it doesn't recognize the `\u` ?

GNU sed version 4.1.2

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/\w/\u&/'
```

`\u` must apply to something; by itself it does nothing; in this case `&` means "whatever matched the search pattern". `g` is to be omitted if you want just *the first* letter; if you include `g` it will make uppercase *all* letters.

Comment: it's not working for some reason... actually what i do is this `sed "s/.*/\L&/g" | sed "s/\w/\u&/"` because i first want to lowercase everything

Comment: `sed -e 's/.*/\L&/' -e 's/\w/\u&/'` absolutely works, I have tested it. Can you try `ls -l | sed -e 's/.*/\L&/' -e 's/\w/\u&/'` as a quick test?

Comment: it just trims the first letter for some reason... weird

Comment: This requires GNU sed. It won't work on standard UNIX / BSD sed.